# Android: custom View change size

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am using OnClickListener on my custom view and this code to enlarge view on click:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (!large)
    {
        this.getLayoutParams().height *= 2;
    } else {
        this.getLayoutParams().height /= 2;
    }

    large = !large;
}
```

but when I click the view nothing happend, view do not change size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaneg your method like this..then it will work..

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
     if (!large)
        {
            params.height = 2 * view.getHeight();     
        } else {
            params.height = view.getHeight()/2;
        }
        large = !large;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: super kali..:))

Answer (score 0):

You have to invalidate your View to tell Android to redraw it :

```
this.invalidate();
```